# Video Camera Zoom

Tags: android, video, camera, zooming

I'm implementing an Android app that record video. I'm trying to implement the zoom functionality but I'm not able to let it work. I haven't not found around any good code. 
I post the piece of code I have tried. this code is inside the OnCreate method in the Main Activity in which I'm implementing the video recording:

```
ImageView test = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zoom);
test.setClickable(true);
test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Context context4 = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setZoom(parameters.getMaxZoom());

        boolean Zoom = parameters.isZoomSupported(); 
        int maxZoom = parameters.getMaxZoom(); 
        if (parameters.isZoomSupported()) {
            if (zoom >=0 && zoom < parameters.getMaxZoom()) {              
                parameters.setZoom(parameters.getZoom()+1);
                parameters.setZoom(zoom);
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                Toast.makeText(context4, "Zoom Setted: "+parameters.getZoom(), duration).show();
            } else {
                // zoom parameter is incorrect
                Toast.makeText(context4, "Zoom NOT Setted", duration).show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So what I have is an image view called "zoom" that when clicked should increase the zoom of the video preview till reaching the max zoom allowed!!! This what I would like to implement in theory but nothing happen when I click the imageview....neither showing any toast! 
I'm testing it on a Nexus s.
Someone knows how to modifiy this code in order to work or someone tried to implement in a different way? If yes how can I do?
PS: The paramameter zoom is defined above as an int initialized to 1.

Answer (score 0):

On the Nexus S it is probably the case that

```
!isZoomSupported()
```

For example: https://code.google.com/p/aokp/issues/detail?id=172 .

This would explain why you would not see any toasts from the code inside

```
if (parameters.isZoomSupported()) {...}
```